# Elasticsearch: getting documents with exactly a certain value in a field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an index with documents that have some repeated textual content, and I need to retrieve the ones that have exactly the same value, not a similar value. So, for instance, consider each of the following lines as the value of the "text" propery of different documents:

- The car crashed
- The car (*)
- He drives the car
- The car (*)

So what I need is to retrieve just the two documents marked with (*). I tried:

```
GET news/_search
{
  "_source": ["text"],
  "min_score": 1,
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : {
        "query": "The car",
        "fields": ["text"],
        "flags": "NONE",
        "minimum_should_match": "100%"
    }
  }
}
```

But it always retrieves all the 4 documents. I also tried with match_phrase and I had the same results.

PS: I need to be able to run both queries: one to retrieve the 4 documents, and other one to retrieve just 2.

This is the mapping:

```
{
  "news" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "tweet" : {
        "properties" : {
          "text" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Yes  I believe the fix needs to be in `mappings`. Can you post the `mappings`?

Comment: sure, give me a minute, but I don't want this to affect all the other searches I do. I still need to be able to retrieve the 4, or just the 2 documents

Comment: Did you try the [Terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html)-Query? Normally this should be used for exact matches. But not on fields of type `text`. Maybe you could additionally store your text field as a not analyzed field and use the terms query on this not analyzed field.... And did you try [Match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html)-Query?

Comment: Yes, but I forgot adding the .keyword :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exact match you should go for `Term Query` of elasticsearch on the keyword type of the field. 
Use this for ex.

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "text.keyword": {
        "value": "The car"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above query will return only 2 results. But if you want to fetch all the results go for `Match` query

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "The car"
    }
  }
}
```

This will return you all the four results.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Richa, this is exactly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: Happy To help :)